# Issue with UITabBarViewController as master of UISplitViewController in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios8.3

For a project that I'm working on, I've put together an UITabBarViewController as master of UISplitViewController in a universal app running in iPad simulator, it used to work fine in iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.2 but with iOS 8.3 it crashes with the message:

Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'Z6l-Hd-h3H-view-7sH-l5-cWr''

Please notice that if you change the simulator to one of version 7.1 or 8.2 it works ok, I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what could be causing this behavior.

Here's an example: https://github.com/AresDev/splitwithtabbar

Thanks for your help.

Here is the stack trace:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02004746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x004eea97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0200466d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   UIKit                               0x00a76e2f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1003
    4   UIKit                               0x00891124 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 270
    5   UIKit                               0x008918bb -[UIViewController loadView] + 295
    6   UIKit                               0x00891aef -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x00892095 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x008e1d2f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 426
    9   UIKit                               0x008e136f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    10  UIKit                               0x008dd52b -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 339
    11  UIKit                               0x008dd2e5 -[UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] + 115
    12  UIKit                               0x008dce91 __51-[UITabBarController _setViewControllers:animated:]_block_invoke394 + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x007b6d4f +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    14  UIKit                               0x008dcd3d -[UITabBarController _setViewControllers:animated:] + 3627
    15  UIKit                               0x008db403 -[UITabBarController _updateLayoutForTraitCollection:] + 302
    16  UIKit                               0x008dae73 __80-[UITabBarController willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke + 69
    17  UIKit                               0x00c36107 -[_UIViewControllerNullAnimationTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 198
    18  UIKit                               0x00c35d9a -[_UIViewControllerNullAnimationTransitionCoordinator _runAlongsideAnimations] + 148
    19  UIKit                               0x008af063 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:] + 399
    20  UIKit                               0x00c1fa10 -[UISplitViewController _setMasterOverrideTraitCollectionActive:] + 127
    21  UIKit                               0x00c1b35a -[UISplitViewController initWithCoder:] + 112
    22  UIKit                               0x00bfa92e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    23  UIKit                               0x00bfa643 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    24  UIKit                               0x00a77c1a -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 189
    25  UIKit                               0x00bfa92e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    26  UIKit                               0x00bfab30 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1253
    27  UIKit                               0x00bfa643 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    28  UIKit                               0x00a76ed0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1164
    29  UIKit                               0x00d34185 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 220
    30  UIKit                               0x00d34301 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 74
    31  UIKit                               0x0072c6fc -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 79
    32  UIKit                               0x0072c984 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    33  UIKit                               0x0072b2f4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1337
    34  UIKit                               0x0074493e __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    35  UIKit                               0x0072a04a -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    36  FrontBoardServices                  0x031c7c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    37  FrontBoardServices                  0x031c772f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x031d9d7c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x01f26050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1b963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1b7bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1aa5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1a88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    44  UIKit                               0x00729a02 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    45  UIKit                               0x0072d106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    46  splitwithtabbar                     0x0000beba main + 138
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x02bf1ac9 start + 1
    48  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the item viewcontroller of UITabBarController as UINavigationController rather than UIViewController
2. You can set MasterController of UISplitviewController as directly to the UITabBarController.
3. Its better to set DetailController of UISplitviewController as a UINavigationController.

see the attached pic

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this fixes de crash and I marked the answer as selected, but I woud like to know what changes from one version to the other that ends up with this behavior.

Comment: When new xcode arrives, I think they are forcing us to stop bad practicing ! ;)